# Unitarily transforming a matrix to a given form

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible, by a sequence of left and right multiplication by unitary matrices, to transform a general $3 \times 3$ matrix to the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} * & * & 0 \\  0 & 0 & * \\ 0 & 0 & * \end{pmatrix}?$$

My hunch is "no", because multiplying, by say a Householder reflector, on the left in order to force the first column to become
$$\begin{pmatrix} * \\  0  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
would have an undetermined effect on the second column -- in effect you lose control of the second column. Is there a "rigorous" proof however that no such algorithm exists for general $A \ \in \mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication with unitary matrices shouldn't change the rank.

Hence it is not possible to transform a non-singular matrix using unitary matrix multiplication.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are right. I voted to delete my own answer which was posted just shortly after yours, which said basically the same thing.